# primefaces datatable search issue

Tags: jsf-2

I am working on a project where I have to use primefaces datatable.It needs one list to populate the data.

The datatable code is posted below.

```
<p:dataTable var="refVariable" value="#{managedBean.listData}" rows="10">

<p:column>
```

.....

```
<p:column>
```

.....

```
</p:dataTable>
```

ManagedBean code

```
private List<Object> listData;

setter method
```

.........

```
gettter method

public List<Object> getListData()
{
listData = service.getDataValues();//call to core method to get the list of object values
return listData;
}
```

Whenever I do any operation ..I mean searching, sorting Call is always going to getter method where I have the actual logic to get the data.
Suppose If I have 10 rows ...If I do any sort operation It is calling 10 times to my getter method.

How can I minimize the call to getter method

Any suggestions greately appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704580/how-to-avoid-unnecessary-fetching-of-data-from-database-in-jsf)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times